# Undergrad project advice

Tags: fluid-dynamics, education

I am presently in my senior year and I am considering fluid mechanics for my thesis.
What area of research of fluid mechanics which is purely analytical and very mathematical since I am an applied mathematician can I look into.
NOTE 1: I am from a 3rd world country and the academic standard is low.
NOTE 2: Please provide references that I can consider.

Comment: Welcome to Physics.SE, Qoma Sanya. What you've asked for here would be either a poll or so specific to you situation that it would never be of help to other people. We don't accept either type of question, so I'm going to close this. I hope you don't be too discouraged.

Comment: If you get to 20 reputation points, you can ask this question in chat.  I've given you an upvote to help you get there.